# SQL: Unable to SELECT joined column

Tags: sql, oracle

I've written an SQL statement to display the department_id, job_id and of employees with the lowest salary, but one of the conditions required me to exclude departments with the names 'IT' and 'SALES', which were only accessible from another table departments. As such I joined the two tables using the shared column department_id and managed to filter the results as needed however, I am unable to select the department_id to display alongside the job_id and salaries. This is what I've managed so far:

```
 SELECT EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID JOB_ID, MIN(SALARY)
 FROM EMPLOYEES JOIN DEPARTMENTS
 ON DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID = EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID
 WHERE JOB_ID NOT LIKE '%REP'
 AND DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME NOT IN ('IT','SALES')
 GROUP BY EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID
 HAVING MIN(SALARY) >= 6000 AND MIN(SALARY) <= 18000;
```

Comment: looks like you have a typo in the selection list, and are as a result using JOB_ID as an alias for EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID (there needs to be a comma between).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, table aliases make the query much easier to write and read:

```
 SELECT e.DEPARTMENT_ID, e.JOB_ID, MIN(e.SALARY)
 FROM EMPLOYEES e JOIN
      DEPARTMENTS d
      ON d.DEPARTMENT_ID = e.DEPARTMENT_ID
 WHERE e.JOB_ID NOT LIKE '%REP' AND d.DEPARTMENT_NAME NOT IN ('IT',' SALES')
 GROUP BY e.DEPARTMENT_ID, e.JOB_ID
 HAVING MIN(e.SALARY) >= 6000 AND MIN(e.SALARY) <= 18000;
```

You need all non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I left out the comma in the select statement because that was the only way it worked, but now I realize that it was because I missed the job_id in group by. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Comma is missing in your query after department id in SELECT - so it considers Job ID as Alias for department ID and displayed as Job ID in query result. But again you don't have Job ID in GROUP BY Clause and need to add that in group by or have to use any aggregate function

```
  SELECT **EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID, JOB_ID,** MIN(SALARY)
  FROM EMPLOYEES JOIN DEPARTMENTS ON DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID=EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID
  WHERE JOB_ID NOT LIKE '%REP' AND DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME NOT IN('IT','SALES')
  GROUP BY EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID,JOB_ID
  HAVING MIN(SALARY) >= 6000 AND MIN(SALARY) <= 18000;
```